# Which is the correct way to send Update Command to SQL Server

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

ConnString = Connection String // StrQuery = Sql Query String

1. First Method

   ```
   Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
   Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter

   con.Open()
   adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(StrQuery, con)
   adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   con.Close()
   ```
2. Second Method

   ```
   Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
   Dim cmd As SqlCommand

   cmd = New SqlCommand(StrQuery, con)

   con.Open()
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   con.Close()
   ```

Data can be inserted to Database using both ways. I want to know which is the better way, and what difference exactly is between them. Any drawbacks in one or the other. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is wrong.  The second way is correct.  You would use a data adapter to `Fill` a `DataTable`, the contents of which you would edit.  Then you'd use the same data adapter to `Update` the database with the changes from the `DataTable`.  If you're not using a `DataTable` then a data adapter is pointless.  It is supposed to group together the four CRUD operations.  If you're just issuing an `UPDATE` directly then use the second option.

Comment: @Yehia, because the use of the data adapter is completely pointless in that scenario.  The two code snippets do exactly the same thing except the first one creates a completely pointless data adapter.  It will still work but it's not the right way to do it.